# Get Request and Response XML in SOAP web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I'm making a call to a web service. The call works as expected in most cases. However, sometimes it fails and for troubleshooting, there is always a request from the developer to send them the request xml and if possible the response xml. How do I get this? I tried using fiddler but I don't know if it is because it is https, I only see some tunnel entries but not the xml sent or received. Sample of the web service code is below:

```
var serviceUrl = "http://190.0.0.1/ServiceLIVE/Service.asmx";
var svc = new LiveEntryService.LiveSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding("LiveSoap"),new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));            
var ret = svc.MakeLiveEntry(0, "001001002", "002002003", 3, "New Site Data", "004", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Comment: You need to step into svc.MakeLiveEntry and see what that's doing. You might be able to see the OuterXml in there if stepping through the code and copy and paste into notepad or something.

Comment: Hmmm. I tried setting through and I had a class that extends System.ServiceModule.ClientBase<>. The method calls base.Channel.MakeLiveEntry(...). Which object should I examine?

Comment: Do you have access to the web service?

Comment: Not at the moment as I'm not close to the server but I tried stepping through yesterday and that was what I saw.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by running the web service and 'Attaching to Process'?

Comment: How do I do that? I usually have a test console application which I use for testing connectivity and debugging? Are you talking about debugging the web service itself? Is so, then no since I do not have access to it as it was done by another team.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (debugging the web service). Does 'var ret' return anything? So if you set a watch on 'var ret' and step through the code what does it return?

Comment: Yes. It works great and returns the right result which is a strongly typed object. In some instances, the value I get is not write and the developer is asking for the xml I sent to that he can analyze it. This is what has prompted the need for me to get the xml that is being sent to the web service.

Comment: I don't know how you would be able to do that without access to the web service. Sorry. My guess is you're sending those parameters to the method MakeLiveEntry in the web service that then creates a soap request and makes it 'text/xml' and then gets the response, which it returns to 'var ret'. Without accessing MakeLiveEntry you can't see what xml is being sent.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway. Still searching though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serious testing of web services download a copy of SOAP UI today. It is relatively simple to get started with it.

You will be able to see and manipulate your requests and responses. It is really worth using this tool for testing.

Disclaimer: I dont work for SOAP UI.

Comment: Thanks. Downloading it now and will test against the service tomorrow.